# indexOf() with repeated value in Java array

Tags: java, arrays, indexof

I'm trying to print the value of each value's index in this array.

```
    Integer[] i = { 0, 2, 3, 4, 4 };
    for (int each : i) {
      System.out.print(Arrays.asList(i).indexOf(each) + " ");
    }
```

Now, I want it to say `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, not `0, 1, 2, 3, 3`.

What do I need to change to get each specific index, and not each value’s “first match”?

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to get at, if you're iterating through the array one at a time, logically, the index of each iteration will be the same as your `i` value...

Comment: @Aominè ah, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your code but if you want to print all the indices of the array and NOT the values you can do this

```
Integer[] i = {0,2,3,4,4};
for (int index = 0; index < i.length; index++) 
{
    System.out.print(index + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicated values in list - you'll return first matching value in your implementation. To fix this - you can create a copy array and when value found in copy - replace it with "null".

Next time duplicated value won't find 1st duplicate, and will return next index.

```
Integer[] i = {0,2,3,4,4};
Integer[] copy = new Integer[i.length];
System.arraycopy( i, 0, copy, 0, i.length );

        for (int each : i) {
            int index = Arrays.asList(copy).indexOf(each);
            System.out.print(index + " ");
            copy[index] = null;
        }
```

> output: 0 1 2 3 4

Sure now you can reorder initial array and it will still return correct indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `Index` of a *specific item* in an array, you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // Create example Arrays
    Integer[] arrayOfIntegers = {1,2,3,4,5};
    String[] arrayOfStrings = {"A", "B", "C", "D",};

    /******Test*******/
    // what is the index of Integer 2 in the arrayOfIntegers
    System.out.println(getIndex(arrayOfIntegers, 2));

    // what is the index of String "C" in the arrayOfStrings
    System.out.println(getIndex(arrayOfStrings, "C"));

    // what is the index of String "X" in the arrayOfIStrings
    // which doesn't exist (expected value is -1)
    System.out.println(getIndex(arrayOfStrings, "X"));  
}

/**
 * This method to return the index of a given Object in
 * the array. It returns - 1 if doesn't exist
 * @param array
 * @param obj
 */
public static int getIndex(Object[] array, Object obj){
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(obj.equals(array[i])){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Output**

```
 1
 2
-1
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to return ***ALL*** Indices found for a ***repeated*** item in an array, you can do something like this:

```
/**
* This method returns all indices of a given Object 
* in an ArrayList (which will be empty if did not found any)
* @param array
* @param obj
*/
public static ArrayList<Integer> getIndices(Object[] array, Object obj){
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if(obj.equals(array[i])){
            indices.add(i);
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

**Test**

```
// Create example Array with duplicates
String[] arrayHasDuplicates = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "Y", "B"};
System.out.println(getIndices(arrayHasDuplicates, "B"));

Output:
[1, 4, 6]
```